# How to handle javascript hyperlinks when js is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have some hyperlinks with `onclick`s. These hyperlinks load content from another page into a div.

The hyperlink looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.page2.html" onclick="gotopage2();">page 2</a>
```

and the code I have in my head section is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gotopage2(){
  window.location("page2.html");
}
```

But this doesn't work as I'd like it to. What I would like to do is:

If JavaScript is enabled, use the onclick.
If Javasccript is disabled, use the href.

the problem is, putting a # in the href will allow the javascript to be executed - but then if javascript is disabled, i won't have any way to put the url in the href!

I don't want to have to go fetch all hyperlinks on a page on document load and take away the href's and I don't like using many . Isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: May I ask what is the point of this? (By the way to disable the effect of `href` just do [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) or even `return false`)

Comment: Sorry, the effect is not as it should be. When I use the link javascript is not detected. So even with javascript enabled it doesn't work because the href has a url in it.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean but here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5bAfg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel the default action of the link.

If you are using intrinsic event attributes, return false from them.

```
onclick="gotopage2(); return false;"
```

If you are writing modern code, call `preventDefault` on the event object.

```
<a href="http://www.page2.html">page 2</a>

<script>
function goToPage(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.location = this.href;
}
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', goToPage);
</script>
```